# Unable to run the QT basic example on emulator

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt-quick

The QT basic application is getting crashed when i run on the emulator by giving the below error messages.

and also giving an error at "import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.4" as QML module not found.

Emulator is with API 28.
QT version name: Qt 5.12.4 for Android x86
Compiler: Android Clang (C, x86_64)

Request you to please help in resolving these errors.

```
I zygote  : Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
W zygote  : Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
I zygote  : Do partial code cache collection, code=28KB, data=20KB
I zygote  : After code cache collection, code=28KB, data=20KB
I zygote  : Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
I QtCore  : Start
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.TestOneMore-diXhlrUpcg6WGCwBjHyxcA==/lib/x86/libQt5Gui.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.TestOneMore-diXhlrUpcg6WGCwBjHyxcA==/lib/x86/libQt5Network.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.TestOneMore-diXhlrUpcg6WGCwBjHyxcA==/lib/x86/libQt5Qml.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.TestOneMore-diXhlrUpcg6WGCwBjHyxcA==/lib/x86/libQt5Quick.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.TestOneMore-diXhlrUpcg6WGCwBjHyxcA==/lib/x86/libQt5QuickParticles.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.TestOneMore-diXhlrUpcg6WGCwBjHyxcA==/lib/x86/libQt5QuickTemplates2.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.TestOneMore-diXhlrUpcg6WGCwBjHyxcA==/lib/x86/libQt5QuickControls2.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80
W linker  : "/data/data/org.qtproject.example.TestOneMore/qt-reserved-files/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80
I Qt      : qt started
W linker  : "/data/data/org.qtproject.example.TestOneMore/qt-reserved-files/plugins/bearer/libqandroidbearer.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80
I Qt JAVA : Can't find '/data/data/org.qtproject.example.TestOneMore/qt-reserved-files/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so'
I zygote  : Do partial code cache collection, code=60KB, data=50KB
I zygote  : After code cache collection, code=59KB, data=49KB
I zygote  : Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
I zygote  : Do full code cache collection, code=121KB, data=85KB
I zygote  : After code cache collection, code=107KB, data=65KB
**E linker  : normalize_path - invalid input: "C", the input path should be absolute**
W linker  : Warning: unable to normalize "C"
**E linker  : normalize_path - invalid input: "C", the input path should be absolute**
W linker  : Warning: unable to normalize "C"
D OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa05d4600, tid 9158
I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9e1060a0: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e1060a0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9dc94880)
**E eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
E eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da**
I zygote  : Do partial code cache collection, code=112KB, data=100KB
I zygote  : After code cache collection, code=112KB, data=100KB
I zygote  : Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
I zygote  : JIT allocated 71KB for compiled code of void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
I zygote  : Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e1060a0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9dc94880)
W linker  : "/data/data/org.qtproject.example.TestOneMore/qt-reserved-files/qml/QtQuick.2/libqtquick2plugin.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80
W linker  : "/data/data/org.qtproject.example.TestOneMore/qt-reserved-files/qml/QtQuick/Controls.2/libqtquickcontrols2plugin.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x80
W libTestOneMore.so: QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
W libTestOneMore.so: qrc:/main.qml:3 module "QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard" is not installed
08-20 11:14:36.167  9133  9151 W libTestOneMore.so:
W libTestOneMore.so: exit app 0
D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e1060a0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9dc94880)


**"org.qtproject.example.TestOneMore" died.**
```

Comment: What is _emulator_? What is OS/Qt version etc? Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i have added OS/Compiler/QT version details.